# How to convert the string value content to the generic `int?` (nullable int)?

Tags: c#, nullable, data-conversion

Having a method with generic output type, I need to convert a string value (read inside the method) to the given type `T` that can also be nullable. The simplified method code looks like this:

```
    public T ReadN<T>()
    {
        string valueStr = "000004346"; // actually read from a file

        // When it should be converted to null for nullable types,
        // return the default (that is null).
        if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != null 
            && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != typeof(string)
            && valueStr.Trim() == "")
            return default;

        // Being here, I know it can be converted to the non-null value.
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(valueStr, typeof(T));
    }
```

When calling the method like:

```
    int? result = ReadN<int?>();
```

I get the exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]'.
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
```

How the conversion of the `string` to the `int?` (passed as the generic `T`) should be done correctly?

**Update after some valuable comments**

The more realistic simplification of the method (still not working, to be solved) is:

```
    public T ReadN<T>(int n, string format="")
    {
        int cnt = reader.Read(readBuffer, 0, n);
        if (cnt != n)
        {
            Log.Error($"ReadN({n}, \"\"): Only {cnt} characters read.");
        }

        string valueStr = new string(readBuffer[0..cnt]);

        // If nullable, the type is not string?, and the string trims to empty
        // then return default of the nullable type.
        // (The warning "Possible null reference return" suppressed.)
#pragma warning disable CS8603
        if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != null 
            && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != typeof(string)
            && valueStr.Trim() == "")
            return default;
#pragma warning restore CS8603

        // Mandatory or conditional (nullable but not empty) DateTime.
        // Format parameter value expected.
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime)
            || Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            Debug.Assert(format.Length == n);
            DateTime t = DateTime.ParseExact(valueStr, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(t, typeof(T));
        }

        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(valueStr, typeof(T));
    }
```

The `reader` and the `readBuffer` are members of the class. It works for `DateTime` -- I had to be more explicit because the `format` defines how the read string encodes the date.

As the `ReadN<T>()` is to be used when building a parser, I want to make the usage as simple and brief as possible. The internals can be more complex, the execution need not to be extremely efficient.

Comment: `Convert.ChangeType` does not do what you think it does: it isn't magic: it cannot convert any type to another, and it only works for a small number of built-in types that implement `IConvertible` - the `ChangeType` method should be `internal` imo, and everyone should be discouraged from using it.

Comment: Can you expect that all of your target types 'T' will implement `IParsable<T>`? If so, you can just use `Parse/TryParse` from this interface (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iparsable-1)

Comment: Is there a reason you're writing a generic method `ReadN<T>` instead of just having a `ReadInt64()` method? Why are you using generics here? (i.e. I don't think this is an appropriate use of generics).

Comment: @Dai Yes, there is a reason.

Comment: @Dai It is to be used in a parser where the read length of the string is passed from outside, and the types can be various -- say based on the width of string to various IntXX, sometimes nullable, sometimes not, but also DateTime... However, all the types probably implement the `IParsable<>` as mentioned in the other comment.

Comment: @pepr The consumer of your code still has to provide type-arguments, and if they can supply type-arguments then they can also specify exact method names - this is why I don't feel this should be a generic method.

Comment: @pepr If you want to use `IParseable` why aren't you using it as a generic type constraint?

Comment: There is nothing generic about converting a `string` to an `int`. You need to create an `int` and thus you need to know the type of the value you are about to create. You should detect the type one way or another and then choose between `int.TryParse`, `DateTime.TryParse`, etc.

Comment: @Dai I have changed my mind. Please write the comment, and I will accept it.

Comment: @pepr I wrote 5 comment replies - I don’t know which one you’re referring to

Comment: @Dai I have decided based on you comment from 12:48 (currently 5 upvotes), but all of them are valuable for me.